# Gitlab: Location of apk after build

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Where is the location of the apk after a successful build with GitLab? I want to push the apk to another server.

My .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
before_script:  
  - chmod +x gradlew
  - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"

dev:  
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define artifacts in your .gitlab-ci.yml. You have to explicitly configure Gitlab to save a specific artifact after build, which will give you access to the artifact browser in Gitlab UI where you can retrieve your apk.

```
artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/*.apk
```

See here for more information :

http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts

http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/build_artifacts/README.html